# UIAlertView Dynamically in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I want to display dynamic UIAlertView and Indicator within it when data is loading from web-service.
Also I don't want any button on UIAlertView. And it will be stopped automatically when data will be loaded successfully.

How can I implement it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WebView then write startAnimating ActivityIndicator in ViewDidLoad and this delegate method will call by itself when your data will be loaded

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
   [ActivityIndicator stopAnimating];    
}
```

Hope it helps.Thanks :)

Comment: Hey Thanks. It Works.
But I don't want any button on UIAlertView.

Comment: UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

Answer (score 2):

Just declar UIAlertView and then your activity indicator, make indicator a sub view to alert view and then when your data has been loaded from web service dismiss with this instance method

```
 – dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:
```

Answer (score 1):

Then use MBProgress HUD or SVprogress HUD

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD