# When to invoke [UIWebView stopLoading] in iphone project?

Tags: iphone

For UIWebView in iphone project, for the method [webView stopLoading], how does it work? Does it really stop all loading related process? Consider the case this UIWebView is loading manifest, how does it deal with?

What's the proper time to invoke [webView stopLoading], during [viewController viewWillDisappear] or [viewController dealloc]?

Any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this if it helps[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186507/uialertview-dynamically-in-iphone-app/10186738#10186738](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186507/uialertview-dynamically-in-iphone-app/10186738#10186738)

Comment: Thanks. Not get answer from that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project I'm doing it like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear
{
    if ([webView isLoading])
        [webView stopLoading];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [webView setDelegate:nil];
    [webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is the proper method, say many open source also use this way.